# Error CS0311 Encountered While Implementing Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, asp.net-identity

I am working on implementing authentication and authorization in my ASP.NET Core application, but I'm encountering an error that I'm unable to resolve. I have a class `AppDbContext` that inherits from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` to handle user-related data. Here is the code:
I have CS0311 Error on AppDbContext

```cs
using AuthenNAuthorizationRoles.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace AuthenNAuthorizationRoles.Services
{
    public class **AppDbContext **: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }
    }
}


I have ensured that all necessary packages are installed and that my Program.cs file is correctly configured for authentication and authorization.

Error : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0311?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0311)

Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this error and how to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
```

Comment: Could you share more details about `ApplicationUser.cs` and `Program.cs` files ?